# Why are these DMVs returning rows for all databases except one?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-permissions, dmv

I am trying to query the DMVs in SQL Server 2008 R2.

On this server are two user databases called *histrx* and *OpenLink*.  To prove I have their names correct:

```
select db_id('histrx') -- Returns 5
select db_id('OpenLink') -- Returns 7
```

If I run the following query, picking out entries for the *histrx* database, I get 25 rows in the result set:

```
select top 25 
    total_worker_time/execution_count as avg_worker_time,
    total_logical_reads/execution_count as avg_logical_reads,
    db_name(s.dbid) as [db_name],
    object_name(s.objectid, s.dbid) as [object_name],
    execution_count,
    plan_generation_num,
    last_execution_time,
    creation_time,
    [text],
    p.query_plan
from
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) s
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) p
where
    db_name(s.dbid) = 'histrx'
order by
    avg_logical_reads desc
```

If I then change the `where` clause to the following, no rows are returned:

```
where
    db_name(s.dbid) = 'OpenLink'
```

I know that there is a significant amount of activity on the *OpenLink* database.  If I look at **Recent Expensive Queries** in the Activity Monitor, I can see entries for *OpenLink*, and I'm pretty sure this is using the DMVs underneath.

- I'm running the Activity Monitor and the DMV query under the same
  login
- That login is the owner of the *OpenLink* database
- If I run `select * from fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'server');` then I can see I have *VIEW SERVER STATE* permissions
- If I remove the `where` clause, I see entries for other databases such as *msdb* and *distribution*
- Here is a screenshot of the mappings for my login.  I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be the owner, but that's a different question.

[image: Screenshot of SQL Server permissions showing db_owner role membership]

Can anyone tell me why my DMV query is returning zero rows for this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [Books Online 2008 R2 > sys.dm_exec_sql_text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> dbid smallint ID of database. Is NULL for ad hoc and prepared SQL
>   statements.

1) So, for this type of SQL statements,  `where db_name(s.dbid) = 'OpenLink'` means `where NULL = 'OpenLink'` and this predicate is evaluated to `UNKNOWN`.

2) `dbid` column is `NOT NULL` for *"non-adhoc and non-prepared SQL"* statements (ex. for stored procedures).

3) For SQL 2008R2 you might get the `dbid` for "ad hoc and prepared SQL statements"  from `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes ( plan_handle )` function ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189472%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) using this query:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    ISNULL(src.dbid,CONVERT(SMALLINT,att.value)) AS my_dbid,
    DB_NAME(ISNULL(src.dbid,CONVERT(SMALLINT,att.value))) my_dbname,
    ...
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    ...
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle) att
WHERE att.attribute='dbid'
```